# python ImportError No module named

Tags: python, import, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install a package called `louvain`, I go through its installation and it is installed :
and I checked it, and it is already in the dis-packages

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): louvain in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-igraph>=0.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from louvain)
```

but when I try to `import`it to `python` I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named louvain
```

How should I import the packages from dist-packages ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: @PeterWood .I get the same error , and what is `community` package ?

Comment: I don't know, I was just [reading the documentation](http://perso.crans.org/aynaud/communities/) for you.

Comment: what does `which -a python` output?

Comment: @Peter Wood.Thanks. but I am not using `networkx` and I Follow the command from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/louvain/)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham : /usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

Comment: well there is your problem, do  `/usr/local/bin/python` then try importing tell me what happens

Comment: Ah, different `louvain`! Disregard my comments.

Comment: thanks @Padraic Cunningham, the problem was that there were two versions installed and before i was working with Python 2.7.5 which was in /usr/local/bin/python ,  but this one was in Python 2.7.6 which was in/usr/bin/python and I wasn't aware of these versions installed.

Comment: `usr/bin/python ` is your system python, you can safely remove the other

Comment: ok, Thanks @ Padraic Cunningham. @PeterWood. thank you for trying to help

Comment: No worries.  If you have issues with pip reinstall it using the /usr/bin/python interpreter with get-pip.py https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham, thanks for the Infos.